# How to Use LLVM JIT to execute c++ ir code on windows

Tags: llvm, jit, clang++, lli

the c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
}
```

use clang & lli:

clang++ -S -emit-llvm  hello.cpp -o hello.ll

lli.exe hello.ll

It reports a fatal error, something like "Program used external function ??_7type_info@@6B@ which could not be resolved". 
How can I resolve that linking issue? the symbol ??_7type_info@@6B@  is defined in?

Comment: You need some [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) implementation

Comment: I used VC 2017 MDd , it has implement C++ runtime library already.  
i need to use llvm libc++ instead vc c++ runtime library?